# Issue with 'Register a Complaint Form' Email Address Configuration in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I am currently working on implementing a 'Register a Complaint Form' on my WordPress website. The form allows users to enter their name, email, order ID, and the reason for their complaint. Upon submission, the information is sent to our customer support dashboard using the email address provided by the user in the form.

However, I have encountered a critical issue with the code I'm using to build this form. It appears to be altering the 'from' email addresses on my WordPress website, causing conflicts with other functionalities. Specifically, it conflicts with the 'from email address' used in Elementor forms, and it also interferes with a plugin I'm using to send review reminders.

I have provided the code snippet below that I am currently using to build the 'Register a Complaint Form':

```
<form id="complaint_form" class="complaint_form" action="" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name</label>  <span>*</span>
    <input class="c_name" id="c_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
    <label for="email">Email</label>  <span>*</span>
    <input class="c_email" id="c_email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    
    <label for="email">Phone Number</label>  <span>*</span>
    <input class="c_number" id="c_number" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    
    <label for="email">Order Number</label>  <span>*</span>
    <input class="order_num" id="order_num" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Order Number" required>
    
    <label for="reason">Reason for Complaint</label>  <span>*</span>
    <textarea class="c_reason" id="c_reason" name="reason" rows="4" placeholder="Enter Message" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="com_but" id="com_but" value="Register">
</form>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#complaint_form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var c_name  = $('#c_name').val();
                var c_email  = $('#c_email').val();
                var c_number  = $('#c_number').val();
                var order_num  = $('#order_num').val();
                var c_reason  = $('#c_reason').val();
                    //  console.log (c_name);
                    //  console.log (c_email);
                    //  console.log (c_reason);
             $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        action:'complaint_email_form_php',
                        c_name: c_name,
                        c_email: c_email,
                        c_number:c_number,
                        order_num:order_num,
                        c_reason:c_reason
                    },
                    success: function( response ) {
                        console.log( 'Custom field updated successfully.' );
                        alert('Complaint Registered Successfully !!');
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function( response ) {
                        console.log( 'Failed to update custom field.' );
                    }
                });
             });
        });         
</script>

<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_complaint_email_form_php', 'complaint_email_form_php' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_complaint_email_form_php', 'complaint_email_form_php');

function complaint_email_form_php() {
    $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
    $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
    $c_number = $_POST['c_number'];
    $order_num = $_POST['order_num'];
    $to_email = 'no.reply.ovenfresh@gmail.com';
    $c_reason = $_POST['c_reason'];
    
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        $subject = "Complaint for " . $order_num . "order number";
        $message = "Full Name: ". $c_name."<br>Order Number: ". $order_num."<br>Phone Number: ". $c_number."<br> Complaint Reason :" . $c_reason;

        if (wp_mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            return true;
            wp_send_json_success();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'original_mail_address');
function original_mail_address()
{

   if (isset($_POST['c_email'])) {
        $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['c_email']);
        return $email;
    }
}

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'email_name');
function email_name()
{
    //return 'Oven Fresh';
    if (isset($_POST['c_name'])) {
        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['c_name']);
        return $name;
    }
}

?>
```

My goal is to ensure that the 'from' email address used in the 'Register a Complaint Form' does not affect other parts of my WordPress website

Comment: You should _never_ set `From:` to an arbitrary customer email address - because that is a good way to get your mails classified as spam on the receiving end. (See also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436/1427878, section titled "Don't use a faux From: sender") Send it from the address that is configured in your system, that you are _allowed_ to send mails for - and put the customer's email into the `Reply-To` header, so that when your customer support clicks "reply", it will automatically populate the recipient address with that one.

Comment: @CBroe I'm using a third party software to raise complaint tickets and it can only reply to `from:` emails, I tried what you said before hand but it's not working with the software.

Comment: Then try to put the `add_filter` calls _into_ your `complaint_email_form_php` function, before you call `wp_mail`- and use `remove_filter` to remove them again afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to ensure that the 'from' email address used in the 'Register a Complaint Form' does not affect other parts of my WordPress website

Then put the `add_filter` calls *into* your `complaint_email_form_php` function, before you call `wp_mail` - and use `remove_filter` to remove them again afterwards.

That way, it will only affect that particular `wp_mail` call, and all others happening elsewhere, outside of this, will stay unaffected.